# CakePHP blank entry on saveField

Tags: php, cakephp, controller

I try to create an edit view that allows users to edit entries of a model called ABC. As soon as a user opens the edit mask for a certain row it should lock the row. I have a tinyint(1) value called 'locked' in the database that will do this. here is the part of the code. It happens on the saveField method, i already checked it. It is strange, because the value is changed on the right record! But somehow it tries to do the same task twice, and I don't know why.

```
function edit($id = null) {

    // select the 
    $this->ABC->id = $id;
    $session = $this->Session->read();


    $this->set('locked',false);


    // save or read the data
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->ABC->read();

        // locking
        if ($this->data["ABC"]["locked"] == true) {
            $this->set('usercanedit', false);
            $this->set('locked', true);
        } else {
            $this->ABC->saveField('locked', true);
        }
   }
 }
```

When I replace the saveField code with this (which is of course stupid and just for testing) it works. this somehow proves that the edit method is called twice. Once without a parameter, or with a wrong one..

```
if($this->ABC->id == 13)
  $this->ABC->saveField('locked', true);
```

Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Are you sure when you open the edit mask you call the method edit() only one time?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the id right before the saveField call, like the book says:

> Set the ID of the model ($this->ModelName->id = $id) just before calling saveField().

In your case:

```
} else {
    $this->ABC->id = $id; // ID should be set right before the saveField call
    $this->ABC->saveField('locked', true);
}
```

Comment: i tried that already. what i find strange is the fact that i have a beforeSave function that should set a date before save. but for those empty rows it is not set. i don't know why. i tried everything.